# Get more details on Linkedin share api 500 Internal Service Error

Tags: linkedin-api

I am posting here because of [LinkedIn has no api support](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/53170/using-stackoverflow-for-api-support?lang=en).
We continue to receive an error for certain token's when using the share api. Our code has not changed and these users have successfully utilized the api in the past.

```
{
  "errorCode" : 0,
  "message" : "Internal service error",
  "requestId" : "AC4KMS1HP3",
  "status" : 500,
  "timestamp" : 1521427562451
}
```

How can we get more information / details about this error?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get a generic response from LinkedIn, using the cases, at [Your Cases](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/cases). They said they would pass along to the api team. At least there was a confirmation of an issue.

> Thank you for contacting LinkedIn, hope this email finds you well.
>
> Douglas, in fact, you've encountered a known issue. I'm very sorry for the inconvenience. Our engineering team is working on it, but there's no estimate as to how long that might take.
>
> We'll do our best to keep you posted. In the meantime, I'll gladly help if you have any other questions!

### ...Later on...

> Douglas, I am sorry we do not have an automated feature to alerts members about such issues. But I have sent this as a feedback to our product team to implement.
> Meanwhile, you may refer to https://developer.linkedin.com/ to contact them. You can also get to the Developers website by moving your cursor over About and selecting Developers at the bottom of your Profile page.

Comment: Me too. I have this problem from last Friday night. Is Linkedin updating its infrastructure?