# LinkedIn API returns 500 Internal Error when posting updates

Tags: linkedin-api

Our application allow our users to post updates on Linkedin profiles and company pages and for this we use LinkedIn API v1

Since Friday LinkedIn API sometime returns 500 Internal Error when posting updates. It affects approx. 20% of our users.

For some other users, the updates is posted correctly but the links are displayed with a small thumbnail.

All updates are posted the same way (code and server), the only difference being the LinkedIn account used.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: 500 means internal error, so it's a bug at Linkedin's and here's the wrong place to ask for support concerning others' services.

Comment: Got same issue, seems same as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361653/message-preview-is-different-depending-on-linkedin-profile?s=2|0.0000 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357215/get-more-details-on-linkedin-share-api-500-internal-service-error?s=3|0.0000

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. Linkedin is indeed directing users of it's public API to Stackoverflow for support issues as their teams are monitoring issues posted here.

Comment: @Junito have you confirmed that it is isolated to the same users? We are having the exact same issues but can not spot a pattern.

Comment: @Allen Yes it's only for isolated users and for them nothing works at all.

Comment: LinkedIn aren't entitled to send people here to ask off-topic questions - StackOverflow sets the rules for the site, not LinkedIn. In addition LinkedIn don't actually pay any attention in practice.